# Cравнение строк произвольного содержания и вывод процента схожести

Tags: c, строки

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void process(char *istr, char *S2)
{
    char *instr;
    instr = strstr(istr,S2); 
    if(instr!=NULL)
    {
      printf("true\n");
    }   

}

void main(void)
{
char S1[20], S2[20];
    char sp[10]=" ";
    char *istr; 
    printf("Enter S1, S2\n");
    gets(S1);
    gets(S2);

    istr = strtok(S1,sp);
    while(istr != NULL)
    {
       process(istr,S2);
       istr = strtok(NULL,sp);
    }          
    return 0;

}
```

Нужно сделать сравнение строк произвольного содержания и вывод процента схожести. Делаю так, ввожу 2 строки, меньшую разбиваю на слова, затем передаю в функцию слово и строку, в случае если слово в строке встречается - инкрементирую, затем высчитываю процент совпадений. Пока что хочу, чтобы выводила true, если слово из первой строки встречается во второй. Пишу именно так, потому что после этого буду решать эту же задачу с потоками. Проблема с этим кодом в том, что он выводит true только если строка, в которой мы ищем слово содержит само слово, например строка 1 - (a b c d) стока 2 - (a) результат - (true), а если строка 1 - (a b c d) стока 2 - (a c) в результате пусто, а должно быть (true true).

Comment: Нужно детально сформулировать условие - что значит "процент схожести". Ведь это может быть содержание одной буквы (возможно, несколько раз), содержание двух букв, двух букв рядом, и т.п. При наличии алгоритма - помощь не задержится.

Comment: Так я же расписал, как пытаюсь сделать. Проще всего, как я считаю, сравнивать слова в строках и в зависимости от количества повторяющихся слов и их длинны высчитывать процент, т к тут такое задание, что каждый понимает по своему, а буквы в примере привел, чтобы было понятнее, в идеале вместо букв будут слова.

Comment: Пока что хочу, чтобы выводила true, если слово из первой строки встречается во второй. А этот код выводит true только если строка, в которой мы ищем слово содержит это же слово и ничего больше, например строка 1 - (aaa bbb ccc ddd) стока 2 - (aaa) результат - (true), а если строка 1 - (aaa bbb ccc ddd) стока 2 - (aaa ccc) в результате пусто, а должно быть (true true).

Comment: Расписать (как я понимаю) - 2% за одну букву, +3% если они идут подряд и т.д. Как вариант, можно использовать [готовые идеи](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%A5%D1%8D%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%B0). `strstr` действительно ищет прямое вхождение строки в строку. Пробел не воспринимается как раздел - простой символ

Comment: Гуглите "расстояние левенштейна", и далее по ссылкам другие аналогичные алгоритмы. *"чтобы выводила true, если слово из первой строки встречается во второй"* -- [man strstr](http://www.opennet.ru/man.shtml?topic=strstr&category=3&russian=0)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> например строка 1 - `aaa bbb ccc ddd` стока 2 - `aaa` результат - `true`, а если строка 1 - `aaa bbb ccc ddd` стока 2 - `aaa ccc` в результате пусто, а должно быть (`true` `true`).

Для начала - очевидно, в этом случае нужны не (`true`), (`true`,`true`), ..., а просто счётчик совпадений. Если, конечно, не нужно дополнительно сопоставлять подстроки, позиции, кол-во их вхождений etc. Это уже совсем другая история.

Алгоритм действий тут простой: разбиваем строку, слова из которой ищем, на эти самые слова (в простейшем варианте это делается с помощью функции [strtok()](http://www.opennet.ru/man.shtml?category=3&russian=&topic=strtok)) и ищем вхождение каждого слова в другую строку с помощью [strstr()](http://www.opennet.ru/man.shtml?category=3&russian=&topic=strstr).

```
#define DELIMITERS " \t\n\r"

size_t count = 0;
char *word = strtok( words, DELIMITERS );
while( word ) {
    if( strstr( string, word ) ) {
        count++;
        printf( "string \"%s\" contain word \"%s\"\n", string, word );
    }
    else {
        printf( "word \"%s\" is not found in string \"%s\"\n", word, string );
    }
    word = strtok( NULL, DELIMITERS );
}
```

В более сложных случаях сначала нужно определиться как именно считается "похожесть". Возможно, имеет смысл воспользоваться аглоритмами наподобие расстояния Левенштейна ([раз](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%9B%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%88%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%B0), [два](https://habrahabr.ru/post/275937/) и т.д.). Или изобретать свой велосипед. Но только после чёткого формулирования что же именно надо считать.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int process(char *s, char *S2)
{ 
    char *instr;
    int col_in = 0; 
    instr = strstr(S2,s); 
    if(instr!=NULL)
    {
     return strlen(s);
    }
    else return col_in;     
}

void main(void)
{
char S1[20], S2[20];
    char sp[10]=" ";
    char *istr;
    int res = 0, col_words=0, tmp;
    double proc;  
printf("Enter S1, S2\n");
gets(S1);
gets(S2);
    if(strlen(S1)<strlen(S2))
    {
    istr = strtok(S1,sp);
    while(istr != NULL)
    {
       res += process(istr,S2);
       printf("%d\n",res); 
       istr = strtok(NULL,sp);
       col_words++;
    } 
    proc = (res+col_words-1)*100/strlen(S2);
    }else{
    istr = strtok(S2,sp);
    while(istr != NULL)
    {
       res += process(istr,S1);
       printf("%d\n",res); 
       istr = strtok(NULL,sp);
       col_words++;
    } 
    proc = (res+col_words-1)*100/strlen(S1);
    }

    printf("%.1lf",proc);   
    return 0;

}
```

Решил задачу таким способом, прилагаю код, вдруг кому пригодится

Comment: Очень неэффективно. Слишком много лишнего, сокращается в 2 раза без потери смысла и читаемости.

Comment: Как именно можно сократить код?

Comment: Выложите код отдельным вопросом с меткой [code-review](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0/info) (почитайте описание метки).

Answer (score 0):

Если строки действительно произвольного содержания, то их нужно сравнивать чем-то типа функции Левенштейна: [https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Расстояние_Левенштейна](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%9B%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%88%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%B0)

Если вы хотите работать со словами, то это делается по-другому. В вашем алгоритме слово "нет" будет выявлено как входящее в строку, содержащую слово "Интернет".

Нужно делить строку на слова по пробельным символом (результат - массивы слов). Потом для флективных языков (русский) использовать стемминг [https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Стемминг](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3) для слов, не входящих в список исключений.

Двадцатью строчками кода отделаться не удастся.